# values of true and false in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I read that in shell,
true command returns 0 => logical true.
false command return 1 => logical false.
But I get surprising results when i run.

```
if [ 0 ]
then
echo "0 is true."
else
echo "0 is false."
fi

if [ 1 ]
then
echo "1 is true."
else
echo "1 is false."
fi

if [ false ]
then
echo "false is true."
else
echo "false is false."
fi

if [ true ]
then
echo "true is true."
else
echo "true is false."
fi
```

I get these results.

0 is true.
1 is true.
false is true.
true is true.

Comment: doesn't this `if [ 1 ]` mean `if 1 exist` or `if 1 is not null` I mean I am neither a unix nor a shell guy but I am curious? `if(1)` It is like that in C,C# and Java as much as I know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The test `if [ 0 ]` tests whether `0` is the empty string (it isn't) and returns true if it is not empty.  The test `if [ 1 ]` similarly tests whether `1` is the empty string and returns true if it is not empty.  Likewise, the other two tests check whether the strings `true` and `false` are empty...

If you want to test the commands, execute the commands:

```
if false; then echo False is true; else echo False is false; fi
if true ; then echo True  is true; else echo True  is false; fi
```

Most machines don't have commands called `0` or `1`, so you can't readily invoke them as commands.

You could also experiment with:

```
if sh -c "exit 1"; then echo Shell exited as true; else echo Shell exited as false; fi
if sh -c "exit 0"; then echo Shell exited as true; else echo Shell exited as false; fi
```

---

In 7th Edition Unix, `/bin/test` (or possibly `/usr/bin/test`) was the test program, but you would normally find a link `/bin/[`.  When it was invoked by the name `[`, it demanded that its last argument was `]`, so you could write a square bracketed condition.  (Macs with macOS 10.14.6 Mojave still have `/bin/[` — it still works.  Linux systems usually have `/usr/bin/[`, and it still works too.)

Shortly after that, the `test` operation was built into the shell, instead of being a separate executable, but the semantics remained largely unchanged.  Because they are now different (built-in vs the executable), sometimes the test operations have different functionality.  POSIX defines a baseline; various shells and systems provide various extensions.

To this day, the `autoconf` suite recommends the use of `test` over `[`, though that is primarily because it uses square brackets for another purpose.

Answer (score 6):

`[` is a command. If passed a non-zero-length string it returns true. If you want to run the `true` or `false` commands then don't run the `[` command instead.

Comment: so we should use `if [expr]` only when expr is to be evaluated? If expr is a shell command then `if expr` alone will do?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm confused when I should go for                                                     `test`, `/usr/bin/test`, `[ ]`, `/usr/bin/[` and nothing (as was the case above). It would be great if someone could explain the real differences and when to use them.

Comment: `test` and `[` are the same thing. If you need to test the return value of a single command for zero or non-zero, don't use them.